# Get ID of row where details match php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php file which is gathering the username and password and checking it against the database, if it matches then the user logs on. Is it possible to get the ID of this row and store this in a variable ready for a session ?

I'm currently using this statement.

```
$query = mysql_query("select * from users where password='$password' AND    username='$username'", $connection);
```

Thanks all

Comment: You really should (salt and) hash users' passwords.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to an **SQL injection**! Always escape user inputs.

Comment: I have at the end of the code ! Thanks for feedback :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way:

```
$query = mysql_query("select * from users where password='$password' AND    username='$username'", $connection);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$id = $row['user_id']; //change user_id to the column name
```

But don't use `mysql_*`, use `mysqli_*` instead.